# Use \nameref without displaying the entire name

Tags: ref, nameref

Say I have a TeX section:

```
\section*{Appendix A: My Name is Blah}
\label{appendix}
```

but I want to refer to "Appendix A" without the ": My Name is Blah". Is there a way to do this? The code `\nameref{appendix}` will spit out "Appendix A: My Name is Blah", but I would like a way to spit out "Appendix A" while still having the ability to click on it and get routed to that section.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Try to give us a minimum working example (MWE) to compile; it makes it much easier for us to help you.  Also, try reading the documentation; `Appendix \ref{appendix}` will do what you want, and is *very* standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy way, but the table of contents will show really ugly for my taste:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[rightlabels]{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents\clearpage

In~\ref{appendix:A} named ``\nameref{appendix:A}'' we can see that\ldots

\section{test 1}
\lipsum[1-10]
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Appendix\space\Alph{section}}

\section{My Name is Blah}
\label{appendix:A}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say.  When I use `nameref` I get the name of the section, not the section itself; to get `Appendix A:  Blah` I would need to type:  `Appendix \ref{appendix}:  \nameref{appendix}`.

But what you want is the simple `\ref` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello}\label{sect}

\nameref{sect}

\noindent Section \ref{sect}

\end{document}
```

The first line will be `Hello`; the second will be `Section 1`.  If you need fancier references than these, there are many packages on CTAN that can help you; but what you're looking for definitely seems to be the simple `\ref` command.